# Cracking an RSA with no padding and very small e

Tags: rsa

I have a project wherein I have to crack a given cipher text encrypted using RSA and have been given N and e. Can someone suggest an RSA attack using a very small exponent e(here e=3) and no padding?

Answer (score 7):

If there is no padding, then you can try the following:

- You can run an exhaustive search on the possible plaintexts. No padding means no randomness; encryption is deterministic, so you can "try" plaintexts and see if one matches the encrypted value when encrypted.
- Without padding, encryption of *m* is *m<sup>e</sup>* mod *n*: the message *m* is interpreted as an integer, then raised to exponent *e*, and the result is reduced modulo *n*. If *e = 3* and *m* is short, then *m<sup>3</sup>* could be an integer which is smaller than *n*, in which case the modulo operation is a no-operation. In that case, you can just compute the cube root of the value you have (cube root for plain integers, not modular cube root).

Comment: Further, the last attack has a simple extension working for short $m$ slightly wider than $n^{1/e}$; we are given $c=m^e\bmod n$ and can find by enumeration $k$ such that $k⋅n+c$ is an $e$th power; then $m=(k⋅n+c)^{1/e}$.